# Retrieve only one specific data in a LinkedList (the data field holds several data)

Tags: java, linked-list

I implemented the LinkedList class from scratch and they have the following methods:
`getHead(), getCount(), addFront(), deleteFront()`

I have a Student class with `constructor(String studentAdmNo, String studentName, String gender, String diploma, int year, String status), get set method, toString()`

and the Node contains method `getData(), setData(), getLink(), setLink(), toString()`

I added the `Student` object into the LinkedList (**and so this LinkedList data field holds several data**; which is String studentAdmNo, String studentName, String gender, String diploma, int year, String status).

However, **I want to retrieve only one data** (which is the `year`) from the data field.

```
for (Node j = LinkedList.getHead(); j!=null; j = j.getLink()) 
        {
            int yearData = ((Integer)j.getData()); //returns everything that is in the data field
            //what I want is something like j.getData().getYear() but there's an error
            }
        }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What does the `getData` method return exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Node.getData()` method returns an `Object` and you have used it to store `Student` objects, then you can cast the returned object to `Student` and call the appropriate getter.

`int year = ((Student)j.getData()).getYear();`

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this example (continue by clicking the little almost invisible button labled next): [Why Generics?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

I think you should make your list generic. I guess that it right now contains `Objects`. In your case, you should declare your classes like `class Node<E>` and `class LinkedList<E>`, and create the linked list as such: `LinkedList<Student>`.

I would also argue against disclosing the `Node` class. See this for a quick overview: [Encapsulation/Information Hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).

Your `getHead()` method should instead return a `Student` directly. Then you could simply do:

```
list.getHead().getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have getters & setters, so simply get the Node from which you want to retrieve the year and make a call using getter for year
Likely the method should be node.getYear();
where node is the instance of Node