# How to look for element in linked list from user input java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, user-input

so I have an assignment for my Data Structures class and I've tried to do as much as I can but I'm currently stuck on this part of the assignment and I need some help. The assignment basically requires you to make a java program that is a student record database that stores 6 variables: id, name, subCode, subName, sem, and year using linked list. This is what I have done so far.

Main class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public int id =0;
public String name= "";
public String subCode="";
public String subName="";
public String sem;
public int year;
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public void Menu() {
     boolean valid = true;


    while (valid) {

        final  String menu[] = {"Main Menu", 
                "1. Register student's subjects",
                "2. Retrieve all students' subjects listing",
                "3. Retrieve a student's subjects listing", 
                "4. Update a student's registered subjects",
                "5. Delete a student's registered subjects",
                "6. Delete a student registration", 
                "7. Exit"};

        for (String menuList : menu)
            System.out.println(menuList);


              switch (scan.nextInt()) {
                 case 1:
                    create();
                     break;

                 case 2:
                list.retrieveAll();
                     break;

                 case 3:
                     //retrieveOne();
                     break;

                 case 4:
                    //update();
                     break;                      

                 case 5:
                    //deleteSub();
                     break;

                 case 6:
                    deleteStud();
                     break;

                 case 7:
                     System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
                     valid = false;
                     break;

                 default:
                     System.out.println("You have not entered a valid option");
                     break;
                 }
     }
 }

public void create() {
System.out.println();
boolean validate = true;

while(validate) {
    try {
System.out.println("Please enter Name");
scan.nextLine();
name = scan.nextLine();
//validate =Validation.validateName(name);


    System.out.println("Please enter Student ID");

    String tempID=scan.nextLine();
//  validate=Validation.validateId(tempID);
    id= Integer.parseInt(tempID);

    System.out.println("Please enter student Subject Code"); 
    subCode=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter Subject's Name");
    subName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter Student's semester");
    sem = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter Student's Year of Study");
    year = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    list.create(id, name, subCode, subName, sem, year);
    validate=false;
/*      list.create(17052960, "Samuel Ho", "CSCP 2014", "Programming 2", "Fall 2017", 2);
    list.create(17040007, "Jodi Mak", "ENVS 1014", "Enviromental Studies", "Fall 2016", 3);
    list.create(17022880, "Yee Hong Chun", "MATH 1024", "Calculus 1", "Fall 2018", 1);
    list.retrieveAll();
    list.deleteAt(1);
    list.retrieveAll();*/


}catch(Exception e) {
validate = true;
}
}
}
public void deleteStud() {
    System.out.println("Enter Student ID of the student you wish to delete");
    int tempID = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();



}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main main = new Main();
    main.Menu();

}
}
```

LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedList {
Node head;

public void create(int id, String name, String subCode, String subName, String sem, int year) {
Node node= new Node();
node.id=id;
node.name=name;
node.subCode=subCode;
node.subName=subName;
node.sem=sem;
node.year=year;
node.next=null;

if (head==null) {
    head=node;
}else {
    Node n = head;
    while (n.next!=null) {
        n=n.next;
    }
    n.next=node;
}
}

public void retrieveAll() {
Node node=head;

while(node.next!=null) {
    System.out.printf("%d %3s %10s %3s %14s %3d\n", 
            node.id, node.name, node.subCode, node.subName, node.sem, node.year );
    node=node.next;
}
System.out.printf("%d %3s %10s %3s %14s %3d\n", 
        node.id, node.name, node.subCode, node.subName, node.sem, node.year );

}
public void deleteAt(int index) {
if (index==0)
    head=head.next;
else {
    Node n = head;
    Node n1=null;
    for (int i =0; i<index-1;i++) {
        n=n.next;
    }
    n1=n.next;
    n.next = n1.next;
    System.out.println("Deleted " + n1.id);
    n1=null;
}
}
}
```

Node class:

```
class Node {
int id;
String name;
String subCode;
String subName;
String sem;
int year;
Node next;
}
```

So this is what I have done, it is far from complete but I need to do it quick and I'm stuck at the deleteStud() method. I need a user input of which id of a student to delete. Then it searches in the linked list and deletes the student. I have implemented to deleteAt a certain index, but have no idea how to search and delete the student from their id. This is will also help my retrieveOne() method where I have to display a student's records from user input of their id.

I hope I'm not to long winded but I really need your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only one specific data in a LinkedList (the data field holds several data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761843/retrieve-only-one-specific-data-in-a-linkedlist-the-data-field-holds-several-da)

Comment: I don’t see your `Node` class.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it simply be the same as your deleteAt function, with the exception that you check node.Id instead of an Index?

Here's a rough crack at a solution (I didn't run this or anything).

```
public void deleteId(int ID){
    Node previousNode=head;
    Node currentNode=head;
    while(currentNode!=null){
        if(currentNode.id==ID){
             previousNode.next=currentNode.next;
             currentNode=currentNode.next;
        }else{
             previousNode=currentNode;
             currentNode=currentNode.next;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Deleted " + ID);
}
```

What this code essentially does, is it goes through all nodes starting from head, keeping track of the current node you're inspecting, and the previous node you inspected.

If the current node's ID is equal to the ID you're looking for, we remove that node from the linked list by adjusting the previous node's next pointer.

Comment: It only works if all student id's are unique from each other. There are supposed to be repetitions for this assignment. Such as if student a has an id of 12345678, he can be repeated in the linked list as long as the semester is not the same. However, when you retrieve or delete, we only want to see this particular student's records. And I can't seem to find a way to do it. Would appreciate if helped. Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelHoLiFeng the code has been adjusted to reflect your request for repeated IDs :)

Comment: Yes Thank you it worked! May I know what the if else statement does? Because it works but I want to understand how it works as well. Also, if I want to retrieve all from the particular student, the code would be similar right?

Comment: @SamuelHoLiFeng the code for your request would be practically the same. The If condition checks to see if the currentNode's Id matches the ID you're looking for, meaning this node is the student you want to delete. If the Id matches, we change the previous node's next pointer to the currentNode's next pointer, effectively removing the student from the list, as nothing will be pointing to his nodes anymore. If the currentNode doesn't match, we just skip it.